# css vertical align text inside absolute responsive div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical center a text inside a responsive div but I really don't find the way to do it without new CSS3 tricks..

Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/M8rwn/

```
.iosSlider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* slider */
.iosSlider .Slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* slide */
.iosSlider .Slider .Slide {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.iosSlider .Slider .Slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 
.slider-prevContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50%;
    color: #595e62;
    text-align: center;
}
.slider-nextContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #595e62;
    background: blue;
}
.slider-next {
    position:absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 50px;
}


#single-slider {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Is the height of the element #single-slider always going to be 500px?

Comment: No, it's responsive. I set 500px just for the example...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I have a solution.

Adjusted HTML:

```
<div class="slider-next">
   <div id='slider-next-inner'>
      >
   </div>
</div>
```

Added CSS:

```
#slider-next-inner{
   position:relative;
   top:50%;
   margin-top:-30px;
   /* Margin-top is 1/2 the elements height (currently it is 59px) */
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/M8rwn/18/

Comment: thank you. But it can't works like this... It's a little bit more complex because it's responsive. It can't have any px inside my next container...

Comment: Are you talking about the margin-top part?

Comment: Yes and also making a div inside a div. It can't be a solution... If you try it with a responsive design it don't work of course...

Comment: The slider-next-inner will always have a set height. (it is just the height of the arrow). So you will only have to adjust the margin-top if you change the height of the arrow.

Comment: it's not working when the single-slider is responsive... (by the way the arrow is also responsive, but it's not a problem, don't care about it...)